# Atom Editor: How to unhide `.env` file in Atom

Tags: atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I've deleted `.*` from `Ignored Names`. 
All the `.` files are now showing in the sidebar (except for the `.env` file).

Why is only this one file hidden? How can I make it visible?

Answer (score 63):

If you look in the settings for the "tree-view" package, it has an option to hide files that are present in the current project's `.gitignore` file. You may have that option set, and have `.env` in the current `.gitignore`.

Preferences > Settings > Packages > search for "tree-view" > click "Settings" button:

[image]

Comment: My tree package is disabled. I'm using Atom Nuclide.

Comment: @GN. I retagged your question with `nuclide-editor`, maybe someone will have a better answer. I'm leaving mine here in case it helps a future Atom reader.

Comment: I am using Nuclide but this worked for me. Thanks for the help @DanLowe

Comment: OMG, that is one stupid default value.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `Atom Nuclide` you can find and uncheck the "Exclude VCS Ignored Paths" option in the *Settings > Core*:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Click in the tree-view pane.
2. Press `i` to toggle hidden files and directories.

Answer (score 1):

It's in nuclide-package -> settings -> NUclide-file-tree and toggle:

- Hide Ignored Names
- Hide VCS Ignored Paths

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable, check below.. I did the same thing.

Atom-> Config
add the following lines at the bottom
"tree-view":
hideIgnoredNames: false
hideVcsIgnoredFiles: false